# i have an issue in debugging and i don't know whats is the reason C#

Tags: c#, sql

i have two images the first one for product , and the second one for Barcode of product . 
i use to create product this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string barcode = CMBIDCAT.Text+"345" + TXTIDP.Text +"012" ;
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(barcode.Length * 20, 50);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            Font ofont = new Font("code 128", 30);
            PointF point = new PointF(2f, 2f);
            SolidBrush blackbursh = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush whitebursh = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
            graphics.FillRectangle(whitebursh, 0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            graphics.DrawString("*" + barcode + "*",ofont, blackbursh, point);
        }
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
        {
            PIC2.Image = bitmap;
            PIC2.Height = bitmap.Height;
            PIC2.Width = bitmap.Width;
        }
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        PIC1.Image.Save(ms, PIC1.Image.RawFormat);
        byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
        MemoryStream st = new MemoryStream();
        PIC2.Image.Save(st, PIC2.Image.RawFormat);
        byte[] byteImage1 = st.ToArray();

        prd.ADD_PRODUCT(Convert.ToInt32(CMBIDCAT.SelectedValue), TXTIDP.Text, TXTNMP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TXTFP.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TXTSP.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TXTTP.Text), TXTDES.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TXTQTE.Text), byteImage, byteImage1);
        MessageBox.Show("تمت الاضافة بنجاح ", "عملية الاضافة",MessageBoxButtons.OK , MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

[i don't know the reason for this issue please any one help me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuFki.jpg) 
 how can i solve this please .

Comment: Did you clicked button 3 prior to button 1. since inn button 1 click event you assigning some value in PIC2.Image right?

Comment: This title is like "I have no idea what I'm doing plz help meh!!!". What do you want to achieve and where's the problem exactly? "My code is not working" is not a description

Comment: i use button 1 to create barcode for my product , button 3 to save the values of my product to tables of SQLdatabase

Comment: I mean before creating barcode you may trying to save it. is this correct or may I missing some thing

Comment: @chris579 no my code is working and when i debugging the app its work but when i arrive to click on button 3 to save all the values of my product its just stop  ,like in the pic

Comment: @JaydipJ i'm not trying this , i write the code of creating barcode before coding the using of button 3 , because the barcode is one value of many values for product

Comment: The half of the relevant code is missing especially the part where the exception is thrown. Nobody can guess what happens between the button click and the save process. Also I don't understand why you initialize a DataTable when you don't use it.

Comment: @chris579 ` private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            PIC1.Image.Save(ms, PIC1.Image.RawFormat);
            byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
            
            PIC2.Image.Save(ms, PIC2.Image.RawFormat);
            byte[] byteImage1 = ms.ToArray(); `

Comment: @chris579 `  prd.ADD_PRODUCT(Convert.ToInt32(CMBIDCAT.SelectedValue), TXTIDP.Text, TXTNMP.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TXTFP.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TXTSP.Text), Convert.ToInt32(TXTTP.Text), TXTDES.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TXTQTE.Text), byteImage, byteImage1);
            MessageBox.Show("تمت الاضافة بنجاح ", "عملية الاضافة",MessageBoxButtons.OK , MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        } `

Comment: Please [edit] post instead of posting code as comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to just comment. But, should you be using a new MemoryStream for your second image?

According to the MSDN you should not write to a stream that has been written to.

[MSDN "Image.Save Method (Stream, ImageFormat)"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142147(v=vs.110).aspx)

Change your code to:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
PIC1.Image.Save(ms, PIC1.Image.RawFormat);
byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();

MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream();
PIC2.Image.Save(ms1, PIC2.Image.RawFormat);
byte[] byteImage1 = ms1.ToArray();
```

Hopefully that works. :)

Comment: i try this give me the same result

Answer (score 0):

Make sure which value is null while debugging whether the Format or the stream, and consider using the "using" statement with memory stream in order for the resources to be freed like the following :

```
        byte[] byteImage1;

        using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            PIC1.Image.Save(ms, PIC1.Image.RawFormat);
            byteImage1 = ms.ToArray();
        }
```

And consider using two memory streams for each image as @Tim.E suggested.